# Why is only one of the two armature animations working?

Tags: animation, armature

I would like to create an animation that should be exported as a GLB file.

[image]

In the animation there are 2 objects that should be animated at the same time (1x motor shaft and 1x conveyor).
To make the GLB file work, I have assigned an armature to each of the two objects and then bound them together using Parent (with automatic weights).
After that I tried to animate both armatures in pose mode by adding the keyframes.

I noticed that the motor shaft moves correctly in pose mode when I change the position of the armature.
Strangely enough this does not work with the Conveyor.
The Conveyor remains in its position although the Armature is changed in the position.

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out...
Can someone of you please look over the file and help me out here?

Thanks in advance!!!

Greetings Michael

Answer (score 0):

As the conveyor is quite a complicated mesh, the automatic weights algorithm fails (an info warning appears on the bottom of the screen when trying the parenting), so you have to weight it manually (which is always prefereable with rigid mechanical objects).

To do so select the conveyor, go to edit mode, select all vertices, select "bone" vertex group and click the assign button.[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Josh! I would never have come up with this solution! It works perfectly!